# Got TypeError: Cannot read property 'passes' of undefined using Cypress when generating mochawesome report

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, cypress

i got confusing error, actually i don't know to how to solve a library issue like this, i tried to generate my cypress test case to mochawesome report below are my *package.json* setup file

```
{
"devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^3.1.5",
    "mocha": "^6.0.2",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.18.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.7",
    "mochawesome": "^3.1.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^1.0.7",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5"
}
```

i think there is nothing problem after i installed them,
then, i do run

> cypress run --reporter mochawesome

Then test completed, after that BOOM, i encountered error like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'passes' of undefined
at Spec.Base.epilogue (/Users/mac/project-cypress/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:318:25)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
at Runner.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Reporter.emit (/Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js:239:55)
at Object.server.startWebsockets.onMocha (/Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/project.js:296:22)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/socket.js:237:36)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:213:7)
at /Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/socket/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'passes' of undefined
at Spec.Base.epilogue (/Users/mac/project-cypress/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:318:25)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
at Runner.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Reporter.emit (/Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js:239:55)
at Object.server.startWebsockets.onMocha (/Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/project.js:296:22)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/socket.js:237:36)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:213:7)
at /Users/mac/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/socket/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

this is the stacktrace i've got, did anyone know to solve this issues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same error when using `mocha` version `6.0.0` or above.

If you could, try using version `5.2.0`, until the problem is solved, and it will work fine.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help, yes its working by using mocha 5.2.0 .

Answer (score 5):

Mocha 6 requires a stat collector to be instantiated

i’ve now updated, tested and released updated modules that fix this with mocha 6, but also retains backwards compatibility with mocha 5 and earlier versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-multi-reporters
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporters

[Example against Mocha 5](https://github.com/YOU54F/cypress-docker-typescript/pull/32)
[Example against Mocha 6](https://github.com/YOU54F/cypress-docker-typescript/pull/22/)

the changes required are minimal

`npm i mocha-junit-reporters`

`npm i cypress-multi-reporters`

in reporterOpts.json

```
{
  "reporterEnabled": "mocha-junit-reporters, mochawesome",
  "mochaJunitReportersReporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "cypress/reports/junit/test_results[hash].xml",
    "toConsole": false
  },
  "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mocha",
    "quiet": true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true
  }
}
```

in cypress.json

```
{
  ...
  "reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "configFile": "reporterOpts.json"
  }
```

See https://github.com/YOU54F/cypress-docker-typescript/pull/22/files

Hopefully the PR's will be merged in the source repo's soon but for now, enjoy

Comment: my fix has now been merged in mocha-junit-reporter now, v1.23.0

Comment: can we include the reporter config in `cypress.json` instead of adding an extraneous file?